# Android create JsonArrays with JsonObject content

Tags: android

I'm trying to create simple `JsonArray` with some `JsonObject` with some mobile numbers, when i try to create this as

```
["data":{"contactName":"xxxxx", "mobileNumber":"0000}]
```

format into `while`

my json object length is `1`, i checked while statement and its work fine without any problem but each put data on json object replaced and length is `1`

```
public static JSONArray getLocalContactsList(ContentResolver cr) throws JSONException {

    JSONArray  contacts = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject contact  = new JSONObject();

    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        final String name         = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String       phone_number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        phone_number = phone_number.replaceAll("\\s+", "").trim();
        phone_number = phone_number.replace("-", "").trim();

        if (phone_number.startsWith("+")) {
            phone_number = phone_number.substring(3, phone_number.length());
            phone_number = "0" + phone_number;
        }
        if (phone_number.startsWith("0")) {
            JSONObject c = new JSONObject();
            c.put("contactName", name);
            c.put("mobileNumber", phone_number);
            contact.put("data", c);
        }
    }
    contacts.put(contact);
    phones.close();
    return contacts;
}
```

problem is this part of code:

```
JSONObject c = new JSONObject();
c.put("contactName", name);
c.put("mobileNumber", phone_number);
contact.put("data", c);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you add a contact to JSONArray only once after the loop finished processing all items. Just move `contacts.put(contact);` into a loop, like that:

```
while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    final String name         = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String       phone_number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    phone_number = phone_number.replaceAll("\\s+", "").trim();
    phone_number = phone_number.replace("-", "").trim();

    if (phone_number.startsWith("+")) {
        phone_number = phone_number.substring(3, phone_number.length());
        phone_number = "0" + phone_number;
    }
    if (phone_number.startsWith("0")) {
        JSONObject c = new JSONObject();
        c.put("contactName", name);
        c.put("mobileNumber", phone_number);
        contact.put("data", c);
    }
    // the next line should be inside the loop
    contacts.put(contact);
}
```

This should fix the bug, but not the whole problem, as was pointed out by [npace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1958659/npace). Consider using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library that will handle the task of converting stuff to `JSONObject`s or `JSONArray`s

Comment: This is a quick fix, but manual JSON serialization is a pain. In my opinion OP should migrate to something like GSON at some point make the code a bit more maintainable.